# please explain this coffeescript construct

Tags: coffeescript

a snippet from a sample:

```
class Animal
  constructor: (@name) ->
```

the documentation says that `@name` is a syntactic sugar for `this.name`. Where does it say that the above function also performs assignment? how? I can see from the generated code that it does, I am just trying to understand the language. why does it perform assignment?

thanks
konstantin

Answer (score 3, accepted):

http://arcturo.github.com/library/coffeescript/03_classes.html

> In fact, CoffeeScript provides a shorthand for the common pattern of setting instance 
>   properties. By prefixing argument's with @, CoffeeScript will automatically set the arguments as instance properties in the constructor.

Basically, calling the argument `@name` means "use this argument to set the `name` property of the new `Animal` instance".